# Issues adding CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create 5 tables (should not be too hard), but I am having issues assigning the foreign keys. PhpMyAdmin gives me this error:

```
Can't create table 'databasexx.gave' (errno: 150)
```

Basically all the tables with no foreign keys are created.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oppbygging;
CREATE TABLE oppbygging (
    gnr INT,
    dnr INT,
    ant INT,
    CONSTRAINT dnr_grn_pk PRIMARY KEY (gnr, dnr)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS onske;
CREATE TABLE onske (
    onr INT,
    pnr INT,
    gnr INT,
    prioriet INT,
    ferdig INT,
    CONSTRAINT pnr_gnr_pk PRIMARY KEY (pnr, gnr)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE person (
    pnr INT,
    fornavn VARCHAR(64),
    etternavn VARCHAR(64),
    fdato DATE,
    CONSTRAINT pnr_pk PRIMARY KEY (pnr),
    CONSTRAINT person_pnr_fk FOREIGN KEY (pnr) REFERENCES onske(pnr)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS gave;
CREATE TABLE gave
(
    gnr int,
    navn varchar (255) UNIQUE,
    prod_tid int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT gnr_pk PRIMARY KEY (gnr),
    CONSTRAINT gave_gnr_fk FOREIGN KEY (gnr) REFERENCES oppbygging(gnr),
    CONSTRAINT gave_gnr_fk FOREIGN KEY (gnr) REFERENCES onske(gnr)

)   ENGINE=InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS del;
CREATE TABLE del (
    dnr INT,
    navn VARCHAR(64),
    lager_ant INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT dnr_pk PRIMARY KEY (dnr),
    CONSTRAINT del_dnr_fk FOREIGN KEY (dnr) REFERENCES oppbygging(dnr)

)   ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I am sure that I am making some sort of obvious mistake, but I just cannot figure it out. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is the relationship view, ignore the Eiendom table:

[image]

Comment: A foreign key mus reference the *complete* primary key. You can't have a reference on a "partial PK". So `person` needs to contain the columns `pnr` **and** `gnr` in order to references `onske`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! You are right, that was a mistake. However I'm still getting this when trying to run the code http://i.imgur.com/1gIHn2O.png

The related code now looks like this
http://i.imgur.com/wUZrOrb.png

Answer (score 0):

TO CREATE ANOTHER TABLE WITH A FOREIGN KEY, THE FOREIGN KEY
SPECIFIED MUST BE THE PRIMARY KEY OF AT LEAST ONE TABLE
THAT HAS ALREADY BEEN CREATED,E.G.

CREATE TABLE 1 WITH THE PRIMARY KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSONS(
PERSON_ID INT(10),
FNAME VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
LNAME VARCHAR(20),
DOB DATETIME,
AMOUNTPAID DECIMAL(15,2),
PRIMARY KEY(PERSON_ID)
);
```

THEN CREATE TABLE 2 WITH THE FOREIGN KEY:

```
CREATE TABLE COMMENTS(
COMMENTID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,    
COMMENTS VARCHAR(500),
PERSON_ID INT(10),
PRIMARY KEY(COMMENTID),
FOREIGN KEY (PERSON_ID) REFERENCES PERSONS(PERSON_ID)
);
```